# Checking action parameters in Rails CanCanCan Authorization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, cancancan

Is it possible to access controller parameters when defining abilities in `ability.rb`?

I have an event and users that can participate in or create that event. It seems like I could create a different controller action for every possible scenario, e.g. a user signs himself up for an event or a creator deletes someone from the event. However I think it would be a lot easier to read to have less actions and be able to define abilities based on what parameters are being passed in from the client.

### Answer

@chumakoff has some good info down below that helped explain how CanCanCan is working. I decided to authorize these actions by default in `ability.rb`, and then raise an error, e.g. `raise CanCan::AccessDenied.new("You cannot delete someone else from this event")`, in the controller if I detect incorrect user/event parameter IDs being sent in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are using cancan's `authorize_resource` or `load_and_authorize_resource` controller helper that calculates user abilities based on controller actions names.

But it's not obligatory to use this helper for all actions. You can skip it for actions having complex ability logic and check abilities manually.

For example:

```
class ParticipationsController < ApplicationController
  authorize_resource except: :create # skiping `authorize_resource` for `create` action

  # ...

  def create
    if creator_adds_someone_to_event?
      authorize! :add_to, @event
    end

    if user_signs_up_for_event?
      authorize! :sign_up_for, @event
    end
    # ...
  end
```

So, you can check many different abilities in the same controller action. Just disable default `cancancan's` behaviour for the action.

Comment: Hey that looks pretty close! Source: https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Authorizing-controller-actions 

Why are you authorizing other actions inside the create action? I was thinking I'd check/authorize inside each respective action. From testing it looks like the `authorize!` keyword applies whatever permissions are set up in `ability.rb`, so I guess the algorithm would be to not create any rules for these actions in `ability.rb`, and then `authorize!` inside the action when permissions are detected to be incorrect. Is that bad practice somehow? Seems a little convoluted.

Comment: It looks like you can manually throw errors in controller actions instead of trying to capture that functionality via `authorize!` - which option do you think is better? `raise CanCan::AccessDenied.new("Not authorized!")` - https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Exception-Handling

Comment: It may be a bad practice to put complex logic in one action. Having ability actions that don't match controller actions is a normal case. 
You should `raise CanCan::AccessDenied` only if `authorize!` doesn't  do exactly what you want. For instance, if you want to change error message.

Comment: What do you mean by ability actions not = controller actions? I can see how spreading out ability logic from ability.rb to different actions could be hard to maintain, but if I want to access client parameters it doesn't seem like there's much of a choice. With all this in mind here's what I'm thinking. Authorize these actions in `ability.rb`, and check parameters inside the controller action. If they reference the wrong user/event, `raise` an error. Sound good?

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing your code and logic. So, good luck! )

Answer (score -3):

Yes there is a debugging tool Named as " pry" . Use that it would help u out. Just use `binding.pry` wherever u want to check the value of parameters in the code and the console will stop executing at that moment so u can check the value  of the parameters.